# How to launch an activity from a notification into the foreground?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, foreground

**Goal:** My goal is to launch an Android activity into the foreground when the user taps on a notification.
If a [task of the app](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) is open, tapping on the notification closes the notification drawer, and the activity opens in the foreground, as expected.

**Problem:** If no task of the app is open, however, upon tapping on the notification, the notification drawer remains in the foreground, and the activity only opens in the background.

**Question:** How to tell Android to close the notification drawer and put the opened activity in the foreground, no matter if the app has opened tasks or not?

**Code snippet:**

```
val intent = Intent(context, SplashActivity::class.java)
intent.addFlags(
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)
NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
    .build(title, text, icon, pendingIntent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a `PendingIntent`.

See how on [Start an Activity from a Notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right you want to close notification drawer when your activity opens.
So please add these two lines in your code when you are opening your activity from notification.

```
Intent x = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);

sendBroadcast(x);
```